# How to stop/remove this error for custom onClicks function in chart.js version 3.3.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

In the project we have a custom onClick handler which runs several function related to fetching data from API regarding that particular data point in the chart. Each time a data point is clicked, all the functionalities work fine but I see this error in console.

I've searched online about this, but couldn't find a substantial solution to this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleEvent')
    at Object.afterEvent (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:557376)
    at callback (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:560145)
    at PluginService._notify (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:554362)
    at PluginService.notify (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:554349)
    at Chart.notifyPlugins (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555428)
    at Chart._eventHandler (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555452)
    at listener (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555333)
    at Chart.event (VM1134 requester-legacy.js:552671)
    at VM1134 requester-legacy.js:560084
afterEvent @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:557376
callback @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:560145
_notify @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:554362
notify @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:554349
notifyPlugins @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555428
_eventHandler @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555452
listener @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:555333
event @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:552671
(anonymous) @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:560084
requestAnimationFrame (async)
nrWrapper @ team-apis:10
(anonymous) @ VM1134 requester-legacy.js:560082
nrWrapper @ team-apis:10
```

Example of the custom click handler:

```
const drilldownHandler = (datasetIndex, dataPointIndex, isValueZero) => {
    setTileActive(report.id);
    populateDrills(report.id, reportGroup, report.data.dataset[datasetIndex].values[dataPointIndex], isValueZero);
    executeScroll();
    return;
  };

_.set(chartOptions, 'onClick', (eve, legendItem, legend) => {
        if (!legendItem[0]) return;
        const { datasetIndex, index } = legendItem[0];
        const isValueZero = report.data.dataset[datasetIndex].values[index]['y'] === 0;
        return drilldownHandler(datasetIndex, index, isValueZero);
      });
```